# Как нарисовать график на основе списков?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Здравствуйте.
Имеются две функции: одна возвращает список с данными, другая тоже. Правда, элементов в них разное количество. Так вот, нужно нарисовать график зависимости значений одного списка от другого. Почему не работает такой метод?

```
def getfreq():
    ...
    massivfreq = []
    for i in range(interval[0], interval[-1]+1):
        massivfreq.append(i)
    return massivfreq

 def getreports():
    ... 
    massivreport = []
    for i in range(interval[0], interval[-1]+1, step):
       massivreport.append(i)
    return massivreport

def buildgraph(massivfreq, massivreport):
    plt.plot(massivfreq, massivreport)
    plt.xlabel('Frequency')
    plt.ylabel('Time reports')
    plt.savefig("test.png")
    plt.show()

print(getfreq())
print(getreports())
print(buildgraph(massivreport, massivfreq))
```

NameError: name 'massivreport' is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В двух словах - разные области видимости. [Статья](http://sheregeda.bitbucket.org/blog/2015/01/24/oblasti-vidimosti-v-python/) по теме.

В строке

> `print(buildgraph(massivreport, massivfreq))`

Вы пытаетесь использовать переменные `massivreport` и `massivfreq`, которые не существуют в пределах глобальной области видимости, но существуют в локальных (в функциях).

Необходимо перед выводом объявить их в глобальной области видимости, и получить для них значения:

```
massivreport = getreports()
massivfreq   = getfreq()
```

Сразу и вызовы `print`'ов можно переделать, с использованием созданных объектов:

```
print(massivfreq)
print(massivreport)
```